When testing for normally distributed data, should I consider all variables before running shapiro.test?
I have a two part question regarding the breakdown of my summary table prior to testing with shapiro.test.
First, here is my data. It is a dataframe of bees with their abundance and body sizes and can be summarized by year, urbanization level, sites, and sex.
> dput(df)
structure(list(Genus = c("Bombus", "Agapostemon", "Bombus", "Xenoglossa", 
"Bombus", "Agapostemon", "Agapostemon", "Agapostemon", "Bombus", 
"Bombus", "Bombus", "Xenoglossa", "Xenoglossa", "Agapostemon", 
"Bombus", "Xenoglossa", "Xenoglossa", "Bombus", "Agapostemon", 
"Agapostemon", "Agapostemon", "Xenoglossa", "Agapostemon", "Agapostemon", 
"Agapostemon", "Bombus", "Agapostemon", "Agapostemon", "Bombus", 
"Agapostemon", "Bombus", "Bombus", "Bombus", "Bombus", "Xenoglossa", 
"Xenoglossa", "Bombus", "Agapostemon", "Bombus", "Bombus", "Bombus", 
"Xenoglossa", "Xenoglossa", "Bombus", "Bombus", "Xenoglossa", 
"Bombus", "Bombus", "Agapostemon", "Bombus", "Bombus", "Agapostemon", 
"Bombus", "Agapostemon", "Agapostemon", "Bombus", "Xenoglossa", 
"Ceratina", "Bombus", "Ceratina", "Bombus", "Bombus", "Bombus", 
"Xenoglossa", "Agapostemon", "Agapostemon", "Agapostemon", "Agapostemon", 
"Xenoglossa", "Agapostemon", "Bombus", "Agapostemon", "Agapostemon", 
"Bombus", "Agapostemon", "Agapostemon", "Xenoglossa", "Agapostemon", 
"Bombus", "Agapostemon", "Agapostemon", "Agapostemon", "Bombus", 
"Bombus", "Bombus", "Xenoglossa", "Bombus", "Xenoglossa", "Agapostemon", 
"Agapostemon", "Bombus", "Bombus", "Bombus", "Xenoglossa", "Agapostemon", 
"Bombus", "Bombus", "Ceratina", "Xenoglossa", "Xenoglossa"), 
    Year = structure(c(2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
    3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
    3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
    2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L
    ), levels = c("2021", "2022", "2023"), class = "factor"), 
    Month = structure(c(5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 
    5L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 
    4L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 
    4L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 
    3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L
    ), levels = c("May", "June", "July", "August", "September", 
    "October"), class = "factor"), Phenology = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), levels = c("Early", 
    "Late"), class = "factor"), Urban.Intensity = structure(c(3L, 
    3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("HIGH", "MEDIUM", 
    "LOW"), class = "factor"), Sex = c("M", "M", "F", "F", "M", 
    "F", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "F", "M", 
    "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "M", "F", "F", "M", "M", "M", 
    "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "M", "M", "F", "F", "M", "M", "F", 
    "M", "M", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "M", "M", "F", "F", "M", 
    "M", "M", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "M", "F", "F", "F", "M", 
    "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "M", "F", "M", "M", "F", "M", 
    "F", "F", "M", "F", "M", "F", "M", "F", "M", "F", "M", "M", 
    "F", "M", "F", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F", "F", "M", "M"), SiteID = structure(c(11L, 
    13L, 17L, 1L, 3L, 8L, 20L, 13L, 14L, 1L, 27L, 19L, 22L, 12L, 
    14L, 17L, 4L, 16L, 15L, 29L, 13L, 19L, 4L, 9L, 13L, 6L, 15L, 
    13L, 15L, 22L, 17L, 13L, 13L, 9L, 24L, 5L, 16L, 20L, 11L, 
    13L, 11L, 19L, 19L, 6L, 18L, 24L, 26L, 3L, 24L, 17L, 3L, 
    11L, 9L, 29L, 3L, 2L, 8L, 27L, 27L, 19L, 27L, 9L, 20L, 12L, 
    20L, 19L, 19L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 22L, 9L, 25L, 12L, 22L, 29L, 19L, 
    22L, 19L, 19L, 12L, 9L, 13L, 11L, 11L, 19L, 13L, 22L, 22L, 
    22L, 14L, 15L, 11L, 3L, 22L, 27L, 3L, 17L, 19L, 19L), levels = c("H02", 
    "H03", "H04", "H05", "H06", "H07", "H08", "H09", "L01", "L02", 
    "L04", "L05", "L06", "L07", "L08", "L09", "L10", "L12", "M01", 
    "M02", "M03", "M04", "M05", "M06", "M08", "M09", "M10", "M11", 
    "M12"), class = "factor"), Intertegular.Width = c(3.46122, 
    1.914, 3.8745, 3.0996, 3.40956, 2.079, 1.881, 1.815, 2.8884, 
    3.20292, 3.51288, 3.1872, 2.8884, 1.848, 4.23612, 3.46122, 
    3.0378, 3.3579, 2.178, 2.31, 2.277, 3.15126, 2.343, 1.881, 
    2.244, 4.18446, 1.848, 1.683, 3.66786, 2.244, 3.30624, 3.3579, 
    4.3911, 4.08114, 2.78964, 3.0876, 3.56454, 1.914, 3.56454, 
    3.46122, 3.46122, 2.739, 2.8413, 3.0996, 4.4322, 3.20292, 
    3.6162, 3.8745, 1.947, 3.04794, 4.18446, 2.013, 3.77118, 
    1.815, 1.749, 3.51288, 3.20292, 1.4442, 3.3579, 1.32, 3.6162, 
    4.02948, 4.08114, 3.1374, 1.815, 2.211, 2.013, 1.848, 2.988, 
    2.211, 3.46122, 1.782, 2.211, 3.82284, 2.046, 1.947, 3.30624, 
    2.079, 3.3579, 1.98, 2.013, 1.716, 3.8745, 3.82284, 3.8745, 
    2.99628, 3.30624, 2.89296, 1.914, 2.013, 3.15126, 3.6162, 
    3.51288, 3.0876, 2.145, 3.66786, 3.6162, 1.5936, 3.0996, 
    2.9382), Wing.Wear = c(0, 1.5, 0.5, 3, 0.5, 0, 0, 1.5, 1, 
    0.5, 1, 1.5, 2.5, 2, 2, 3, 1.5, 3, 1, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 2.5, 2, 
    1.5, 0.5, 0, 1, 1, 3.5, 1, 3, 5, 3.5, 1, 1.5, 0.5, 0, 0, 
    4, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3.5, 0, 2, 2, 0, 5, 1, 1, 0.5, 0, 2, 1, 0, 
    2, 0.5, 0, 2.5, 3.5, 1, 4, 1, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 3.5, 0.5, 
    0, 0.5, 1.5, 0, 0, 0, 5, 4, 0.5, 3, 2, 2, 2.5, 0, 4, 0, 0.5, 
    0, 0, 5, 0.5, 4, 0, 2, 5, 4.5, 0, 2), count = c(1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -100L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))

> head(df)
  Genus       Year  Month     Phenology Urban.Intensity Sex   SiteID Intertegular.Width Wing.Wear count
  <chr>       <fct> <fct>     <fct>     <fct>           <chr> <fct>               <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>
1 Bombus      2022  September Late      LOW             M     L04                  3.46       0       1
2 Agapostemon 2022  August    Late      LOW             M     L06                  1.91       1.5     1
3 Bombus      2023  September Late      LOW             F     L10                  3.87       0.5     1
4 Xenoglossa  2022  August    Late      HIGH            F     H02                  3.10       3       1
5 Bombus      2022  September Late      HIGH            M     H04                  3.41       0.5     1
6 Agapostemon 2021  May       Early     HIGH            F     H09                  2.08       0       1

# Added the count column because each row is a single individual (measured ONLY once) so this is how I obtain abundance

Now, I am testing abundance for each genus and for each sex, then I will be running Kruskal.Wallis tests (if not normally distributed) to see how abundance differs with Urban.Intensity and with Year.
But how should the summarized table look prior to this? If I want to test for abundance normalization for just Agapostemon ignoring sex this is my example:
# Just consider Genus, Year, and Urban.Intensity
summary <- df %>%
  group_by(Genus,Year,Urban.Intensity) %>% 
  summarize(Body.Size.Avg = mean(Intertegular.Width), Abundance = sum(count), Wing.Wear.Avg = mean(Wing.Wear))  %>% 
  filter(Genus=="Agapostemon")

> shapiro.test(summary$Abundance)

    Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  summary$Abundance
W = 0.9278, p-value = 0.4963  # NOT SIGNIFICANT; data is normal

# Include the Sex Variable
summary <- df %>%
  group_by(Genus,Sex,Year,Urban.Intensity) %>% 
  summarize(Body.Size.Avg = mean(Intertegular.Width), Abundance = sum(count), Wing.Wear.Avg = mean(Wing.Wear))  %>% 
  filter(Genus=="Agapostemon")

> shapiro.test(summary$Abundance)

    Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  summary$Abundance
W = 0.90641, p-value = 0.1397  # NOT SIGNIFICANT, data is normal

# Include SiteID variable
summary <- df %>%
  group_by(Genus,SiteID,Sex,Year,Urban.Intensity) %>% 
  summarize(Body.Size.Avg = mean(Intertegular.Width), Abundance = sum(count), Wing.Wear.Avg = mean(Wing.Wear))  %>% 
  filter(Genus=="Agapostemon")

> shapiro.test(summary$Abundance)

    Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  summary$Abundance
W = 0.47972, p-value = 4.82e-09  # SIGNIFICANT, data is NOT normal


So really I have two main questions:

I would have to include the Sex variable so I can filter out only females or males afterwards, but do I need this variable when testing for normal distribution of all individuals, regardless or sex? Is it okay if my initial summary table for all individuals is broken down differently than when I look at females or males?

If I already have Urban.Intensity, I get confused if I should still break the summary down by SiteID because if I am testing for Abundance ~ Urban.Intensity, do I need SiteID at all if I already have Urban.Intensity? I guess should we consider the variable's distribution across our variable of interests only (i.e., Urban.Intensity), or we should always consider it across all sample sites (SiteID AND Urban.Intensity should be included; or just SiteID)?



Related

This just explains what normality testing is for. I understand it's overall premise but I don't understand when to consider some variables over others, especially when I get highly different results. I just want to know if I should include all variables I would be testing in the summary table prior to shapiro.test. The main one being if Sex should be included when I am considering all individuals and if SiteID is needed if I am testing with Urban.Intensity

On the contrary, it's rarely of any importance except descriptively whether marginal distributions are (close to) normal or not.  But it's certainly futile to test Sex (a categorical variable) or SiteID (an arbitrary identifier?) for similarity to any continuous distribution.

Ok so if I am going to be testing for significant differences in abundance across urbanization levels and years, for females and males of each genus - what I gather is that testing abundance normality should not consider Sex or Urban.Intensity. Those are just my variables of interest. What matters will be abundance across the sample region, overall. And then for example if looking at just females, I would just filter my dataset for females for Agapostemon (as an example) and then check it's abundance across sites again.

The point is that you are asking about the best way to do something you probably shouldn’t be doing at all, and the link I posted gets into why normality testing is rarely helpful. (Its hard, even if not always impossible, to say the best way to do something you shouldn’t be doing at all.)

In my particular case, it has been predetermined that we do need to test for normality for this dataset. It is common practise with this type of biological data. Do you have a suggestion for my initial question about the variables?

It might be common practice, but that doesn't make it correct. See this page for why choosing a subsequent test based on a preliminary normality test isn't wise. Insofar as there is an issue with normality, it's having a normal distribution of errors around model-predicted values. Fit the model, then see if the distribution of residuals is close enough to normal, for example with a normal q-q plot.

If what you want really is common practice, it is -- as @Dave  I think is also saying -- somewhere between dubious and  misguided. Counts that measure abundance can be zero or positive and are usually positively skewed. The normal distribution isn't a natural reference distribution . It would be a better idea to think directly about a model that makes biological and statistical sense for your problem.

You could also consider moving directly to a generalization of the Wilcoxon or Mann-Whitney tests, ordinal logistic regression with a proportional odds model. See Frank Harrell's resources. "The Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney two-sample rank-sum test and the Kruskal-Wallis test are special cases of the proportional odds model."

Can you clarify what your "unit" is? How to you obtain multiple values, say for 1 genus, and 1 sex? Yes, I can add the counts and see that this genus has 14 male, and 16 females; so what? What statistic can you do? You need multiple observations of the male vs. female counts of that genus; how to you aggregate the counts to get thses muktiple observations from which then one can do statistical analysis? You seem to have a total of 100 counts, and 72 subcategories (4 genus, 2 sex, 3 years, 3 urban intensities; so on average you have 1 or 2 counts per subcategory?? Something does not compute...

As far as I could see, none of your variables can be drawn from normal populations; the numeric ones are either integer or necessarily positive. The  Shapiro-Wilk null is certainly false in every such case, there can be no point testing a hypothesis you know for sure (a priori) is false. There may be some value in considering the extent to which the degree and kind of non-normality of the DV (conditional on IVs) may matter for the properties of whatever inference you plan on doing but the test won't tell you that. In regression, inference doesn't rely on normality of any of the raw variables.

Based on your recent set of questions on Cross Validated, may I respectfully suggest that you consult the York University statistical consulting service https://www.yorku.ca/research/scs/ ? Troubleshooting your statistical analysis pipeline remotely/on the internet is going to be frustrating for all concerned ...

Sigh I have tried but they are all booked until next month. Hence why I decided to come here to try and move things along. I'll have to just wait till they have openings.

As many comments have pointed out, there is no rationale for the normality tests that you propose.
Critically, as @NickCox noted, categorical predictors like Sex can't possibly have a normal distribution. As @Glen_b said: "there can be no point testing a hypothesis you know for sure (a priori) is false."
Other issues, related to continuous predictors that might come close to being normally distributed, are nicely summarized by @Glen_b:

In regression, inference doesn't rely on normality of any of the raw variables.

The classic "Is normality testing 'essentially useless'?" page on this site, linked from a comment by @Dave, goes into much detail. Briefly:

You don't need to know at all whether your predictor variables have normal distributions.

You don't need to know whether your outcome variables have normal distributions.

In ordinary least squares regression, normality of errors around model predictions can simplify arguments related to inference, but with a large number of observations (as you seem to have, based on other questions you've asked) even that might not matter. What matters is whether the coefficient estimates can be expected to have close to a normal distribution.

In practice, normality testing tends to end up under-powered for small samples and, in large samples, too likely to detect "statistically significant" deviations that make no practical difference.

Some types of outcomes, like counts of animals for abundance, are better dealt with in ways other than ordinary least squares.


If you have count data for outcomes, normality testing is irrelevant. Use a method that is designed for count data (e.g., Poisson, quasi-Poisson or negative binomial regressions), or use ordinal regression (which can be considered whenever the outcomes have a rank order, and is a generalization of things like Kruskal–Wallis tests that you are already willing to use).

If you must fit a linear (mixed) model to your data, i.e. treat abundance as Gaussian — this is arguably suboptimal, as in @EdM's last bullet point, but not definitively wrong — and you must test the Normality of your residuals (this is also problematic but not definitively wrong, for the reasons described in @EdM's bullet points 3 and 4), then you should run the Shapiro-Wilk test on the residuals for each model or sub-model that you want to consider. You should not be testing the marginal distributions for Normality; anyone who suggested that is just wrong.
I'm still worried about the example you gave (I'm still not sure I really understand either your scientific or your statistical questions ...)
If I take your first summary, fit a linear model, and test the residuals for Normality ...
summary <- df %>%
  group_by(Genus,Year,Urban.Intensity) %>% 
  summarize(Body.Size.Avg = mean(Intertegular.Width), Abundance = sum(count), Wing.Wear.Avg = mean(Wing.Wear))  %>% 
  filter(Genus=="Agapostemon")

m1 <- lm(Abundance ~ Year + Urban.Intensity + Body.Size.Avg + Wing.Wear.Avg, data = summary)
shapiro.test(residuals(m1))
## W = 0.93003, p-value = 0.5164

... I can congratulate myself on failing to reject the null hypothesis that the residuals are Normal, but the residuals don't look particularly Normal:
plot(m1, which  = 2)


This wonky distribution of residuals occurs because here I've fitted 7 parameters to a data set with only 8 data points. But even this big a deviation can't reject the null hypothesis with only 8 data points!
If I fit a slightly more sensible model (y ~ Year + Urban.Intensity), I get a more sensible Q-Q plot. (Here we also fail to reject the null, but we've already seen that doesn't mean much ...)

